# maximum number of shadow copies that a windows sever system can maintain for each volume?

Tags: tags

From my mcsa book it is 64 copies for each volume. Although I am not sure exactly what this means?

Does it mean 64 shadow back ups of every file on the volume?

Or does it mean only 64 files can have shadow back ups?

Windows server latest one will not allow me to put the year for some stupid reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can actually be a total of 512 snapshots on the same volume. The 64 snapshot max is for shared folders.

The snapshot is a recovery point. So you can have up to 64 versions of one file/folder on a shared folder.

Comment: I assume all the files in the folder can then have the ability to reinstall previous version?

Comment: That's correct. They will revert back to the selected state.

Comment: Thank you for your help getting to grips with this a bit now

Comment: You don't by any chance know how much memory is used by shadow files? So if I had a 1mb word document would the shadow file also be 1mb?

Comment: I personally can't say for certain. You should be able to run this: `vssadmin list shadowstorage` and get the following output:

`C:\>vssadmin list shadowstorage
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line
 tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.

Shadow Copy Storage association
For volume: (C:)\\?\Volume\{clsid}Shadow Copy
Storage volume: (C:)\\?Volume\{a488ed41-38e8-11de-abc2-806e6f6e69
63\}Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 5.547 MB (0%)
Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 1.5 GB (3%)
Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: UNBOUNDED (100%)`